# WCAG 2.1 compatibility with shinydashboard app form label

Tags: r, shiny, accessibility, shinydashboard, wcag

I developed an app using rshiny, https://smandape.shinyapps.io/mmdit/. I am trying to make it WCAG 2.1 accessible. I am using WAVE (Web accessibility evaluation tool) to check for accessibility. Currently, the errors popping are related to 'missing form label'. These errors are specifically for the code fileInput or rabiobuttons (5 errors are on Data import tab). For example, around the following code. WAVE shows the error for the placeholder for fileInput.

```
fileInput("ss_ID",
   label = "Upload one or more single source data",
   multiple = TRUE,
   accept = "text/plain")
```

I am not sure what / how in the rshiny code this should be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fileInput accessibility was one of the things changed in the Shiny v1.6 release: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/upgrade.html

> Closed #2929: Fixed keyboard accessibility for file picker button: keyboard users can now tab to focus on fileInput() widget. (#2937)

Are you definitely using v1.6? It looks like you are, so you may have identified a bug in the shiny framework.

EDIT: I had a look at the code for the fileInput control, and it looks to me like the input and label elements aren't properly linked together. I reported it as an issue: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3426